# I want export report using datatable in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, dom

I am using datatable ( they are provide filtering) and after filtering i want to export in csv.
Export only filtering data only. How to possible in codeingniter?

Comment: https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/

Comment: these options export whole table. Example i am searching Fiona, and after that click on any option (CSV, EXCEL, PDF) but the generated file show all records of table.